# MainStoryBoard Orientation for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When I start with my MainStoryboard.storyboard file in Xcode I begin by removing any support for portrait orientations. However, when I go to my MainStoryboard.storyboard file the Screen is still in the portrait position. My question is how can I change the screen in the .storyboard file to become horizontal? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MainStoryboard.storyboard - select the attributes inspector on the right, then select the `Landscape orientation` option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get your entire application to just be landscape? You can set that up in your Target summary

[image: on the left pick your project -->target-->summary-->supported orientations]